# Import a dataframe with googlesheets4 in a Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, google-sheets, import, googlesheets4

How can I read a sheet from google sheets and use it in RMarkdown, without having to answer the authorization question?

```
url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tAeMng_wLlZfDfeeLzgV8h7vGqWmFhqQv1AAXf60HtU/edit?usp=sharing"

df <- googlesheets4::read_sheet(url, sheet="sensib-fungic")
```

> The googlesheets4 package is requesting access to your Google account. Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token. Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort.

Comment: The file would need to be public—otherwise, how would you get access to it if not by logging in? Alternatively, if you have access to the file, download it in a separate script and write it to a file your markdown file will have access to

Comment: Thanks! by the way do you know how to import a sheet with token?

Comment: It will give you options to log in & authenticate. Outlined in the [docs](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: The new `googlesheets4` should only ask for authorisation the first time, then give you the option to cache the credentials in $HOME/.R/gargle.